# Porque não é possível usar operadores de comparação com NaN?

Tags: ciência-da-computação, ponto-flutuante, ieee-754

> **NaN** - A propriedade global NaN é um valor especial que significa Not-A-Number (não é um número).

O curioso é que não é possível realizar operações de comparação com essa propriedade quase mística. Apresentando uma característica não-reflexiva aonde `NaN === NaN` é `false`.

Fiz logo abaixo um código JavaScript executável apenas para testar o conceito, mas poderia ser qualquer linguagem de programação.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
for(var i  in spans){
 var span = spans[i];
 if(span && typeof span.getAttribute == 'function'){
  var exp = span.getAttribute("data-evaluate");
  console.log(exp, eval(exp));
  span.innerHTML = "Expr: "+ exp + " ------------ :> " + eval(exp);
 }
}
```

```html
<span data-evaluate="true"></span><br> <!-- eval control -->
<span data-evaluate="isNaN(NaN)"></span><br><!-- NaN control -->
<span data-evaluate="NaN === NaN"></span><br>
<span data-evaluate="parseInt('A') === NaN"></span><br>
<span data-evaluate="parseInt('1') === NaN"></span><br>
<span data-evaluate="parseInt('B') === parseInt('B')"></span>
```

Se em seu código costumas realizar cálculos aritméticos é possível que chegue à um momento que o `NaN` apareça naturalmente, seja numa conversão de tipo (`string` para `int`, por exemplo) ou a soma com `undefined`'s.

Qual é o conceito, a matemática por trás dessa anomalia e o que torna os `NaN` tão confusos que fazem com que `NaN === NaN` retorne um valor falso embora humanamente falando deveria retornar `true`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O `NaN`, `+inf` e `-inf` são tentativas de modelar
situações de excepção, erro, indeterminações e *overflows* ligados
à aritmética. As representações em vírgula flutuante (ex `double` do C)
têm convenções para representar estes *pseudo números*.

Há várias situações que retornam (descambam) `NaN`, `+inf` ou `-inf`.

Comecemos por um caso mais intuitivo -- `inf`:

```
5 / 0    = +inf
-5/ 0    = -inf
n + n ...= +inf  se tiver havido overflow
log(0)   = -inf
```

Os casos de `NaN` resultam frequentemente operações com `inf` ou
a "indeterminação" 0/0:

```
0 / 0     = NaN
5/0+ -5/0 = +inf -inf = NaN
+inf * 0  = NaN
inf / inf = NaN
+inf -inf = NaN
sqrt(-1)  = NaN

NaN + ... = NaN
NaN / ... = NaN
NaN * ... = NaN

5 * +inf  = +inf
-2 * +inf = -inf
5  / inf  = 0
```

Os vários `NaN` não são iguais entre si -- daí `NaN == NaN` ser falso.
As comparação envolvendo `NaN` e `inf` são em geral indefinidas:

```
+inf > +inf      ???
NaN  > NaN       ???
0/0  > sqrt(-1)  ???
```

Sugiro a leitura do manual [data.represent](http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/solaris-forte/manuals/c/user_guide/data.represent.html), onde este assunto é expandido.

Answer (score 6):

> NaN são gerados quando operações aritméticas tem como valores:
> *undefined* ou *unrepresentable*. Como valores, não fazem necessariamente
> condições de overflow. NaN também resulta da tentativa de conversão e
> valores não numéricos para valores numéricos para que o valor numérico
> primitivo seja disponível.

Essa conversão de valores geram valores binários arbritários impedindo operações aritméticas, o óbvio seria que `NaN === NaN` resultasse num valor boleano positivo, já que estamos olhando para apenas para o "NaN" como se fosse uma constante, e na verdade ele não é. Por exemplo `"A" * "A"` e  `parseInt("blabla")` resultam em `NaN` porém são completamente diferentes em seu valor numérico primitivo.

Nos [cálculos de ponto flutuante (IEEE 754)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), `NaN` não é o mesmo que o `Infinity`, embora ambos sejam tipicamente tratados como casos especiais em representações de ponto flutuante de números reais, bem como em operações de ponto flutuante. Uma operação inválida também não é o mesmo que `overflow` aritmética (que pode retornar um infinito) ou um `underflow` aritmético (que retornaria o número normal mais pequeno, um número normal ou zero).

Uma comparação com um `NaN` sempre retorna um resultado não ordenado, mesmo quando comparado consigo mesmo. Os predicados de comparação são sinalização ou não-sinalização; As versões de sinalização indicam a exceção de operação inválida para tais comparações. Os predicados de igualdade e desigualdade não são sinalizadores, de modo que `x == x return false` pode ser usado para testar se `x` é um `NaN` silencioso. Os outros predicados de comparação padrão estão todos sinalizando se eles recebem um operando `NaN`, o padrão também fornece versões sem sinalização desses outros predicados.

Resumindo o `NaN` não representa o conjunto de todos os números reais. E valores reais infinitos produzirão o mesmo resultado de ponto flutuante finito ou infinito independente das substituições. Impedindo que operações aritiméticas sejam executadas sobre este tipo de dado.

Comment: `valores binários confusos impedindo operações aritiméticas` Isso não faz sentido. Todo valor binário é um valor numérico discreto. Não há como ser confuso nem como ser impossível ou impraticável a aplicação de aritmética.

Comment: Alterei o termo `confuso` para `arbritários` , dessa forma faz mais sentido neste contexto. Já que tem relação com a arbritariedade na precisão 
 aritimética de tais conversões que geram NaN.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta curta é "*Porque definiram assim*".

Para elaborar melhor e dar um pouco mais de embasamento, segue abaixo uma adaptação [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715), cujo [autor](https://www.linkedin.com/in/stephencanon/) diz ter sido membro do comitê IEEE-754 - que por sua vez, é responsável pelo [padrão IEEE 754](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/112052), que define todo o funcionamento dos números de ponto flutuante (do qual o `NaN` faz parte).

Além da tradução/adaptação, também juntei o texto com outras fontes (tanto do SOen quanto de outros lugares) e alguns adendos meus, a fim de dar um panorama mais geral sobre o motivo de `NaN` não ser igual a ele mesmo.

---

#### Adaptação da [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715) para a pergunta "*Qual a justificativa para todas as comparações com `NaN` retornarem `false`?*"

> Primeiramente, os números de ponto flutuante não são [números reais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number), e a aritmética de ponto flutuante não satisfaz os axiomas da aritmética real. A [Lei da Tricotomia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics)) (que diz que todo número real ou é negativo, ou positivo, ou zero) não é a única propriedade da aritmética real que não se aplica aos números de ponto flutuante, e nem é a mais importante. Existem outros casos, como por exemplo:
>
> - A soma não é associativa.
> - A lei distributiva não se aplica.
> - Há números de ponto flutuante que não possuem inversos.
>
> Esta lista poderia continuar por horas... Enfim, não é possível especificar um tipo aritmético de tamanho fixo que satisfaça **todas** as propriedades da aritmética real que conhecemos. O comitê IEEE 754 tinha que decidir entre seguir todas as regras ou quebrar algumas delas. A decisão foi guiada pelos seguintes princípios:
>
> 1. Quando possível, ter o mesmo comportamento da aritmética real.
> 2. Quando não for possível, tentar fazer com que as violações sejam previsíveis e fáceis de diagnosticar (ou o mais próximo possível disso).
>
> Por exemplo, o predicado `(y < x)` está perguntando se `y` é menor que `x`. Se `y` for `NaN`, então ele **não** é menor que nenhum outro valor de ponto flutuante, por isso a resposta é necessariamente `false`, para qualquer valor de `x`.
>
> Eu disse que a Lei da Tricotomia não se aplica à valores de ponto flutuante. No entanto, há outra propriedade similar que se aplica. A cláusula 5.11, parágrafo 2 do padrão 754-2008 diz o seguinte:
>
> > *Quatro relações mutuamente exclusivas são possíveis: "menor que", "igual", "maior que" e "não-ordenado". A última se aplica quando pelo menos um dos operandos é `NaN`. Todo `NaN` deve ser considerado não-ordenado com relação a qualquer coisa, inclusive ele mesmo.*
>
> Por mais que o tratamento de `NaN` possa exigir código extra, geralmente é possível (embora nem sempre seja fácil) estruturar o código de forma a tratar `NaN`'s corretamente. Quando não for possível, poderá ser necessário um código adicional, mas é um preço pequeno a se pagar pela conveniência que o fechamento algébrico trouxe para a aritmética de ponto flutuante.
>
> ---
>
> Muitos podem argumentar que teria sido mais útil manter a Lei da Tricotomia e a propriedade reflexiva da igualdade (que diz que "*qualquer coisa é igual a ela mesma*"), pois definir que `NaN` é diferente dele mesmo não parece preservar nenhum axioma com o qual estamos familiarizados. É compreensível que muitos simpatizem com esta ideia, mas acho que vale a pena dar um pouco mais de contexto.
>
> Meu entendimento ao conversar com o Professor Willian Kahan (autor [deste artigo](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF) e considerado o ["Pai do Ponto Flutuante"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan)) é que a definição de `NaN != NaN` tem origem em duas considerações pragmáticas:
>
> - `x == y` deveria ser equivalente a `x - y == 0`, na medida do possível. Além de ser um teorema da aritmética real, isso faz com que a implementação da comparação (no nível do *hardware*) seja mais eficiente em termos de consumo de espaço, o que era de extrema importância na época em que o padrão foi criado. Vale notar, porém, que esta regra é violada quando `x` e `y` são iguais a infinito, então este item não é um grande motivo por si só; embora pudesse ter sido alterado por exemplo para `(x - y == 0) or (x and y are both NaN)`).
> - O mais importante é que não havia um predicado como `isnan()` na época em que o `NaN` foi formalizado na [aritmética do processador 8087](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8087). Ele foi necessário para prover aos programadores um meio conveniente e eficiente de detectar `NaN` e que não dependesse das linguagens de programação implementarem uma operação como `isNaN()` (o que poderia levar anos <sup><sub>lembre-se, era outra época</sub></sup>). Sobre isso, Kahan escreveu no [artigo já citado](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF):
>
> > *Se não tivesse um jeito de se livrar do `NaN`, eles seriam tão inúteis quanto os Indefinites (conceito similar dos [computadores CRAY](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/compute/hpc/cray.html)). Assim que um `NaN` é encontrado, seria melhor que o processamento fosse interrompido em vez de continuar por um tempo indeterminado até chegar a uma conclusão indefinida. É por isso que algumas operações com `NaN` devem retornar resultados que não são `NaN`. Quais operações?*
> >
> > *É inevitável que as pessoas discordem sobre quais seriam essas operações, mas isso não lhes dá o direito de resolver estas questões fazendo escolhas arbitrárias. Toda função real (não lógica) que produza o mesmo resultado em ponto flutuante para todos os valores numéricos finitos e infinitos passados como argumento deveria produzir o mesmo resultado se o valor for um `NaN`.*
> >
> > ***As exceções são os predicados `x == x` e `x != x`. Estes são respectivamente 1 e 0 para todo valor infinito ou número finito `x`, mas o inverso se `x` for `NaN`. Estas são as únicas diferenças excepcionais entre `NaN` e números, nas linguagens que não possuem uma constante similar a `NaN` ou um predicado como `isNaN(x)`.***
>
> Talvez este pragmatismo tenha sido equivocado, e o padrão poderia ter obrigado a criar algo como o predicado/operação `isnan()`. Mas isso teria tornado quase impossível o uso do `NaN` de forma eficiente e conveniente, pois o mundo ainda teria que esperar vários anos até que as linguagens de programação o adotassem. Não acredito que teria sido uma escolha razoável.
>
> Sendo bem direto: o resultado de `NaN == NaN` não vai mudar. É melhor aprender a conviver com isso em vez de reclamar na internet (*nota: a [pergunta original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164) tem um tom que pode ser entendido como "reclamação"*).

<sup>*A partir daqui não é mais a tradução da resposta do SOen, e sim minha conclusão ao lê-la.*</sup>

---

## Meu entendimento

Pelo que entendi, um conjunto de decisões foram tomadas levando-se em conta o contexto da época (hardware/software, princípios matemáticos e de *design*, etc). O `NaN` poderia ter sido implementado de várias maneiras, como por exemplo um erro/exceção que parasse a execução do programa. Optou-se por um valor "especial" com um comportamento "fora da curva", de forma a permitir que o programa continue executando (e bastaria verificar se o resultado foi `NaN`, para então tomar as ações apropriadas, como por exempo interromper o algoritmo).

No fim, acabaram decidindo que `NaN == NaN` deve ser falso, pelos motivos já explicados acima. De certa forma foi uma escolha "arbitrária", mas pelo menos houve um raciocínio por trás e todo um embasamento técnico (e claro que também poderiam ter definido que `NaN == NaN` é verdadeiro, mas o fato é que não fizeram e agora temos que conviver com isso).

Para mim, esta é a única resposta correta para "*Por que é assim?*". `NaN` não é igual a ele mesmo porque decidiram que é assim. Qualquer outra "resposta" na verdade está falando sobre os motivos que - no meu entender - potencialmente levaram à decisão:

- "*`NaN` não é um número, por isso não faz sentido ele ser igual a ele mesmo.*"
- "*`NaN` equivale a um valor indeterminado (não tem um valor de fato), por isso não tem como ser igual a nada.*"
- "*`Nan` é um caso especial.*"
- etc...

Estas frases, a meu ver, explicam mais o raciocínio que *pode* ter levado à decisão do que o motivo real dela ter sido tomada. O motivo real é: considerando tudo que já foi dito acima (o contexto da época, os princípios de manter-se fiel à aritmética real até certo ponto, etc), acabaram decidindo que `NaN` ser diferente dele mesmo era a "melhor" opção.

<sup><speculation>Se tivessem decidido que `NaN` é igual a ele mesmo, talvez hoje estivéssemos discutindo se não deveria ser diferente, usando os mesmos argumentos acima :-)</speculation></sup>

Outras respostas e links que pesquisei sempre seguem esta linha de explicar que `NaN` é um "valor especial", "diferente" e por isso tem esse comportamento distinto dos números "normais". No fim, ele não é considerado um número de fato (por isso é chamado de "*Not a Number*"), e sim um tipo de *placeholder* que representa um valor ou estado indefinido. [Esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37266652), por exemplo, defende que o nome não é bom porque confunde, e que deveria se chamar "Exceção Numérica" ou algo do tipo. Isso deixaria mais claro seu comportamento distinto e talvez causasse menos estranhamento ao ser usado (ou não, agora não temos mais como saber).

O `NaN` seria, de certa forma, o equivalente ao [conceito matemático de *Undefined* (Indefinido)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_(mathematics)), quando uma expressão não tem um valor associado. Tanto que muitas operações matemáticas que são consideradas indefinidas produzem `NaN` nas linguagens de programação que usam o IEEE 754, como dividir zero por zero ou subtrair um infinito do outro, que geralmente resultam em `NaN` (além dos outros casos já citados em [uma das respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/220426/112052)).

Esta é, aliás, a linha de raciocínio usada por muitos para explicar o seu comportamento tão peculiar (se não tem valor definido, não tem como ser comparado com nada, nem com ele mesmo - mas novamente, isso explica um dos motivos que pode ter pesado para a decisão final, mas não é "a resposta" em si).

Enfim, no fundo a resposta é "*Porque definiram assim*" (com embasamento, claro, mas ainda sim uma decisão "arbitrária").