# Retornando NaN em função

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá, tenho um formulário com um radio button, caso seja escolhido a opção "Entrada" o form correspondente ao nome "Valor Saida" é desabilitado e vice-versa.
Eu tenho uma função que calcula a soma do valor da entrada e saida de um elemento e retorna o resultado, porém, quando mostro no HTML retorna: NaN:

Segue função:

```
$scope.getTotal = function(){
  var t = 0;
  var s = 0;
  var total = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < $scope.contatos.length; i++)
  {
    s = s + parseFloat($scope.contatos[i].valor);
    t = t + parseFloat($scope.contatos[i].valorsaida) * -1;
    total = t + s;
  }        
  return total;
}
```

Meu html chamando a função:

```
Saldo: R${{getTotal()}}
```

Meu modelo:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    module.exports = function() {
     var schema = mongoose.Schema({
        nome: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        valor: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        valorsaida:{
            type: Number,
            required: false
        }
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) retorna `NaN` se a entrada não for numérica. Isso é esperado.

A próxima coisa a levar em conta é que a soma de qualquer número com `NaN` resulta em `NaN`.

Fica a questão então de porque uma (ou ambas) dessas duas instruções abaixo resulta em `NaN`:

```
parseFloat($scope.contatos[i].valor)
parseFloat($scope.contatos[i].valorSaida)
```

Talvez tenha a ver com o formulário desabilitado? Eu não entendo nada de angular... Mas se não fosse o angular, eu diria que isso é algo a investigar.

Se você desejar tratar o valor `NaN` como zero, você deve utilizar a função [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), que diz se o parâmetro informado é `NaN`. Assim:

```
let a = isNaN(NaN); // a === true;
let b = isNaN(0); // b === false;
```

Essa função existe porque [a comparação normal, através dos operadores `==` e `===`, entre `NaN` e qualquer outra coisa dá falso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220226/1658). O motivo disso é por especificação da linguagem.

```
NaN == NaN // dá falso
NaN === NaN // também dá falso
```

Voltando ao seu cálculo, ele pode ficar assim:

```
let valor = parseFloat($scope.contatos[i].valor);
let valorSaida = parseFloat($scope.contatos[i].valorSaida);

s = s + (isNaN(valor) ? 0 : valor);
t = t + (isNaN(valorSaida) ? 0 : valorSaida) * -1;
```