# O que é IEEE 754?

Tags: terminologia, matemática, números

Aqui no site, temos diversos exemplos de perguntas que falam sobre "problemas" relacionados ao `float` ou `double`, geralmente sobre a imprecisão dos valores retornados em cálculos, como estas abaixo:

- [O que é zero negativo e zero positivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260685)
- [Resultado impreciso em cálculo com números quebrados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5642)
- [Que tipo de dados (double, float) eu devo usar ao representar uma temperatura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328110/que-tipo-de-dados-double-float-eu-devo-usar-ao-representar-uma-temperatura)

Eu vi que a maioria dessas respostas citam o tal do *IEEE 754*.

Mas do que ele se trata? O que é o padrão IEEE 754?

Comment: IEEE (Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers) Standard 754 for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic. Veja: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 e também https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Representações numéricas — fixa e flutuante

Existem duas formas principais para se representar números reais em binário:

- Ponto fixo (*fixed point*)
- Ponto flutuante (*floating point*)

Em síntese, pontos fixos são representados através da fixação do [ponto binário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point). Portanto, *fixa* o tamanho da parte inteira e fracionária do número a ser armazenado.

- Valores à esquerda desse ponto são maiores que 1 (2, 4, 8 ...);
- Valores à direita desse ponto são menores que 1 (½, ¼, ⅛ ...).

O ponto fixo pode simplificar o processamento de números reais, embora imponha significativas limitações no intervalo e precisão dos números que podem ser armazenados, uma vez que o ponto binário é, literalmente, fixado.

Já pontos flutuantes são o meio mais comum de se representar números reais em binário. Em resumo, utiliza o padrão binário da [notação científica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), de modo que possui três partes:

- O sinal (que é representado através de um *bit* à esquerda do número);
- O número base (também pode ser referido por mantissa), que determina a *precisão* do número a ser armazenado;
- O expoente, que representa o *intervalo* do número a ser armazenado.

Observe que o número total de *bits* que podem ser utilizados nessa representação é limitado (32 *bits* em máquinas de precisão simples ou 64 *bits* em máquina de precisão dupla). Desse modo, uma maior precisão exigirá em um maior número de *bits* necessários para a mantissa, o que implicará na redução do número de *bits* disponíveis para o expoente, o que diminuirá o intervalo do número.

Pense em números com ponto flutuante binários como notação científica binária.

### O padrão IEEE 754

Note que, embora exista uma definição para representação de números, não existe, de fato, um padrão para estandardizar esse tipo de operação no que tange aos números reais de ponto **flutuante**.

Em face dessa necessidade de padronização, o Instituto de Engenheiros Eletricistas e Eletrônicos definiu, em 1985, a primeira versão do padrão IEEE 754 (também conhecido como padrão IEEE para aritmética de ponto flutuante). Foi fortemente baseado nos trabalhos de [William Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan).

Esse padrão resolveu diversos problemas, como:

- Formatos aritméticos (conjuntos de dados de decimais e binários de ponto flutuante);
- Formatos para troca padronizado (codificações que podem ser utilizadas para o intercâmbio de valores numéricos de ponto-flutuante de modo eficiente e compacto);
- Regras de arredondamento padronizadas;
- Operações aritméticas (como funções trigonométricas);
- Padronização de como lidar com exceções em casos opcionais (como *overflow*, divisão por zero etc).

Note então que o padrão, em tese, "*criou pouca coisa nova*". O principal objetivo dele foi *padronizar* a utilização de tecnologias e técnicas já existentes para facilitar em tópicos como os acima colocados.

Atualmente, a maioria das arquiteturas e sistemas já utilizam esse padrão, o que não era verdade há algumas décadas. Imagine como era difícil trocar representações numéricas entre duas máquinas que representavam números reais de modos diferente?

Diversas versões dessa especificação já foram publicadas. A mais recente data de 2019.

---

Não vou me estender muito em como funcionam cada uma dessas regras. Para isso, consulte a página na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (ou a própria especificação).

Também não vou explicar (novamente) como a representação postulada pelo IEEE 754 funciona, uma vez que já foi explicada [nesta excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/69296), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260701/69296) também, embora mais brevemente, e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/328129/69296).

Comment: Dentre as respostas citadas, os dos primeiros links são para a mesma resposta. Eu ia editar e remover um, mas comentei aqui porque talvez você lembre qual era a resposta para corrigir o link.

Comment: Obrigado, @RafaelTavares! Tenho certeza que eram para ser três links mesmo, mas nesse ponto não consigo mais me lembrar de qual era para ser o terceiro. :P Todavia eu ainda tenho planos para atualizar essa resposta, então arrumo quando fizer isso. Mas pode editar, se quiser.