# Por que o método Math.toRadians retorna um valor inexato?

Tags: java, matemática, float, números

Eu estava programando um método no qual eu precisava converter um valor de graus para radianos e pensei se essa conversão já não existia no Java. Pesquisando na internet eu descobri o método `Math.toRadians`.

O problema é que, em quase todos os sites que eu li sobre esse método, diz-se que o mesmo retorna um valor inexato — uma aproximação do valor em radianos.

> The conversion from degrees to radian is generally inexact.

Por quê? Qual seria a diferença entre usar o `Math.toRadians` e o cálculo abaixo?

```
double radians = (degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você converte um ângulo na unidade grau para radiano?

A *fórmula* usual está na própria pergunta. Dado um ângulo `x` de graus, determina-se seu `α` em radiano por: `α = x * π / 180`.

Vejamos, por exemplo, um ângulo de 90°. Substituindo `x` na equação acima, temos `π/2` radiano.

Embora 90° seja facilmente representável por um número inteiro (`90`) em um computador, como você representaria `π/2`?

Até o momento, o ser humano (aliás, o computador) sequer conseguiu calcular todos os dígitos de π. É por isso que a conversão nunca será, de fato, exata.

De acordo com a documentação, o método `toRadians` retorna um número do tipo `double`. Internamente, para armazenar esse `double`, o Java utiliza um valor binário de 64 *bits*, de acordo com as normas constadas na [especificação IEEE 754](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/493901/69296).

[Os dígitos de π já ultrapassam os 6 terabytes de memória.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Valor_de_%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000008-QINU%60%22%27%7F) É impraticável armazenar todos esses dígitos em um mero espaço de 64 *bits*. E, mesmo que esse espaço estivesse disponível, a exatidão ainda não seria alcançada, uma vez que o número é irracional (não é possível computar todos os seus dígitos).

Na Matemática a exatidão existe porque você não avalia, de fato, o número π (3.14...). Se alguma expressão Matemática contém o π, você só deixará a letra grega π lá, indicando que é o número, mas não o computa, propriamente falando.

O método `toRadians`, por outro lado, não pode deixar o π intocado, ao contrário da Matemática. Por exemplo, se você passar o número 90, a implementação computará a expressão `Math.PI / 2`, onde [`Math.PI`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI) é uma constante que **aproxima** o valor de π. Percebe a diferença? Como o computador está computando a expressão com uma aproximação de π, perde-se exatidão.

---

E em relação à diferença para o código que está na pergunta: não há. Claro que a implementação do Java pode ser *minimamente* diferente daquela expressão, mas no fundo é a mesma coisa.

Ambas são equivalentes e igualmente inexatas. É um “problema” que decorre do modo como números são armazenados por um computador. É similar à [famigerada imprecisão da expressão `0.1 + 0.2`](https://0.30000000000000004.com/) quando avaliada sob as regras da aritmética de ponto flutuante (normatizadas pela referida IEEE 754).