# Existe diferença entre “exatidão” e “precisão” em contextos de computação?

Tags: terminologia, números

Recentemente, apareceu no site uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/511639/69296) que trata da “*inexatidão*” do valor retornado pelo método `Math.toRadians` do Java. No entanto, em outros lugares (como nas respostas [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5642/69296)), utiliza-se o termo “*precisão*”.

Não estou afirmando que nenhum dos textos utilizou os termos de modo incorreto, utilizei-os apenas para fim de demonstrar que, nesta área, os dois termos podem aparecer frequentemente. Até onde sei, o significado é bem parecido, mas talvez exista alguma diferença.

Gostaria de saber se, no contexto da Ciência da Computação, há diferença entre o significado de **exatidão** e de **precisão**. Se sim, qual é? Ou esses termos podem ser utilizados (formalmente) de modo intercambiável?

Comment: Precisão : "3.absoluto rigor na determinação de medida, peso, valor etc.; exatidão." Eu sempre penso, em sintaxe e semântica. Essas duas palavras com sua sintaxe em Português tem a semântica como mencionado. No contexto de Ciências da Computação, no campo da teoria, você pode fazer uso delas no contexto que lhe convier, na prática em sua raíz toda sintaxe será convertida para binário e a semântica fica implícita nas instruções independente do que elas possam significar em um alto nível.

Comment: (não canônico) Exatidão é precisão absoluta. Quanto mais precisão, você TENDE à exatidão. Exemplo: uma peça (ideal) com exatos 6.332214mm. Um paquímetro dará precisão maior na medição do que uma régua, um micrômetro mais ainda, mas talvez nenhum dê o valor exato. Mas claramente você sabe qual deles tem mais precisão para fazer a medição. Cada mecanismo existe para aliar precisão necessária com facilidade de uso. O nível de precisão adequado difere conforme cada uso, e tem caso que precisa exatidão. Não se usa float - por mais precisão que tenha - em valor monetário, o valor tem que ser exato.

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270869

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nunca vi algo específico para a toda computação. Em pontos específicos da computação pode ser que o termo tenha alguma especificidade ([de fato tem definição](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision#In_information_systems)) ou pode ter isso usado de uma determinada forma, ainda que não seja o consenso geral. Tentarei mostrar isso usando o contexto fornecido na pergunta que acredito ser o mais importante.

## Definição formal

Na [Wikipedia tem um verbete falando justamente sobre essa diferença no geral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision), para ver a importância do tema.

Os termos não podem ser usados formalmente de maneira intercambiável, até porque possuem definições diferentes e claras.

**Exatidão** é sobre a característica que algo tem de estar próximo da realidade.

[image: Flechas no centro do alvo]

**Precisão** é sobre a característica que algo ter detalhes suficientes para entender a informação corretamente.

[image: Pessoa consertando mecanismo pequeno e sofisticado com uma lente de aumento]

Estou colocando com minhas palavras que entendo ser mais simples do que pode ser lido no artigo acima. Lá está mais exato. E como sempre, a Wikipedia nem sempre é a resposta mais canônica e exata possível.

Exatidão e precisão têm graus. Existe o exato absoluto e existe o exato em nível baixo. Mas acho que isso não nos serve muito.

## Informalmente ou como <strike>usamos</strike>uso

Na minha interpretação, que pode não ser a formal, é que se não for o exato absoluto é inexato. Mas pelas definições que encontrei parece que não é bem assim, baixa exatidão pode ser chamada de exata por causa desses graus.

Se levar isso a ferro e fogo desta forma, algumas respostas minhas não estão tão certas assim porque eu separo muito bem o que tem baixa exatidão como sendo inexato, mas que pode ser preciso. [Alguns lugares que usei os dois termos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20exatid%C3%A3o%20precis%C3%A3o).

Usei muito para falar sobre valores monetários. Pra mim, e já vi em vários lugares essa definição, o valor monetário deve ser exato, deve ser exato absoluto.

Tipos de ponto flutuante binário não conseguem ser exatos, por ser uma aproximação, e pode ter o detalhe necessário (o fato de ser positivo ou negativo, as grandezas para todos valores possíveis ou os centavos ou fração deles que se espera).

Pra mim quem deveria ter graus é a precisão, algo é mais ou menos preciso, acho que ser mais ou menos exato é o mesmo que estar mais ou menos grávida. Pelo menos é assim nos cenários dos exemplos da pergunta.

Informalmente acabam sendo intercambiados, eu mesmo devo ter feito aqui e ali porque eu só fui me atentar à real definição depois que comecei usar o SOpt (um dos motivos para usá-lo foi justamente me forçar buscar mais acurácia (que é o mesmo que exatidão :D).

A pergunta agora me fez ver até um pouco melhor sobre o assunto para dar uma resposta mais exata possível :) O que me fez ver que até a interpretação que eu usava não era perfeita, ainda que eu goste dela, acho que ela dá uma ideia melhor, e poderia ser sobre isso que o AP quer saber.

## Tentando comparar os usos em um contexto

[image: Comparação com as 4 situações no eixo de precisão e exatidão]

Pela definição formal geral adotada, esses tipos flutuantes binários podem ser considerados exatos, ou seja, eles podem não dar o valor real, desde que todas as vezes, nas mesmas condições, ele dê o mesmo resultado. E eles dão. Portanto tecnicamente eles deveriam ser chamados de exatos, pelo menos em algum nível. Não gosto disto, acho uma definição inexata :)

Pela minha definição esses tipos são inexatos, mas precisos, já que possuem uma aproximação suficiente para a maioria dos casos. Pela definição formal eles são melhores que precisos. Eles seriam só precisos se cada momento você obtivesse um valor um pouco diferente (ou igual só por coincidência), mas não é o caso. Toda vez que tiver um 0.3 real no computador, usando um tipo flutuante binário, na mesma implementação, dará um valor muito próximo disso, não exatamente ele, mas sempre será esse mesmo valor.

Então vamos tentar interpretar o gráfico acima de um jeito que as definições confluam.

Vamos entender o círculo como algo microscópico e o que está dentro do círculo não pode ser observável por ninguém ou algo. Se está dentro é tudo a mesma coisa. Então fica fácil perceber que se algo sair do círculo é fora da realidade e é inexato.

Mas a precisão complica porque ela só faz sentido se olharmos várias amostras e no contexto que queremos, olhamos apenas uma. Ela aceita que há uma certa aleatoridade quando pegamos um valor.

## Falta informação canônica contextual

Eu sou um crítico de algumas definições da área, ou da falta de definições mais formais e universais. [Tem muita coisa que eu gostaria que tivesse um definição melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429851/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-mapa-um-dicion%C3%A1rio-um-array-associativo-e-uma-tabela/515971#comment943918_515971), mais exata :P.

Eu acho que dá margem para eu continuar usado da mesma forma na computação básica, assim como vi outras pessoas o fazendo. O exato é aquilo que não é inexato, é absoluto, é perfeito. O que não é absolutamente exato pra mim só pode ser (ou não) preciso, mas jamais dizer que ele tem alguma exatidão. Pelo menos em computação. Mas não posso impor minha vontade, não tenho como argumentar tão bem como o fiz em [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

Eu acho que necessitamos de uma definição mais formal para nossa realidade, porque não fazemos experimentos e vemos se obtemos o mesmo resultado, isso não nos serve bem (para a computação em si, pode servir para o domínio de alguma aplicação que fazemos).

Então uso o termo **exatidão** como sendo algo que é a realidade, de forma exata absoluta, não meço os graus de exatidão.

E uso o termo **precisão** para dizer sobre a amplitude da medição, ou seja, em que grandeza eu consigo chegar. Eu posso ver só os milhões de unidades, ou milhares, ou centenas, ou unidades (muito comum), ou posso ver frações de unidade seja pela casa da unidade de fração decimal, da dezena (o mais comum em valor monetário), da centena, milhar, etc.

Note que estou usando os termos em um contexto específico da computação e não para toda ela.

Eu consigo achar material que fala assim, mas é uso intuitivo, não achei definição formal falando o mesmo que eu (ainda não desisti).

Achei [algo no livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Zu-HAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT413&lpg=PT413#v=onepage&q&f=false) que é "a bíblia" da computação, não é uma definição, mas é um uso que mostra que o caminho é este.

## Exemplos da pergunta

O primeiro exemplo da pergunta está correto, é assim como usamos, como documentamos. Do jeito que entendemos, aquela pergunta usa o termo correto, inclusive veio da documentação. O resultado saindo do círculo bem "estreito" dá um número que não é o que queremos quantificar, ele não mostra a mais pura realidade, só algo perto dela. Nada tem a ver com precisão aí.

Estritamente falando, e também pela definição que vejo as pessoas usando na computação, principalmente no contexto usado lá, o segundo exemplo está errado, de alguma forma.

Lá não foi usado o termo "inexato", que é o correto a dizer ali, por qualquer definição que se adote, e isso já é um erro da pergunta/resposta. E usa "impreciso" que não é o caso, também por qualquer definição.

Pela definição que encontramos na Wikipedia, e é corroborada por várias fontes, ele tem precisão porque todas as vezes o erro é igual, está dentro do que se espera, ele não varia. Você não soma 0.1 com 0.2 e cada hora dá um valor diferente, apenas não dá exatamente 0.3.

Mas para essa análise isso não serve porque em computação só não é determinístico o que você não tem controle e esse tipo de operação é sempre sob controle.

E pela definição que eu e outras pessoas usamos na computação, ele tem uma grandeza muito boa de dígitos na parte fracionária, tem detalhes suficientes, talvez mais do que sejam necessários, portanto tem precisão, tem a precisão do valor inexato.

Você pode contestar e dizer que pela definição geral o termo "precisão" não cabe aqui e nem deveria analisar, nem deveria olhar se tem detalhe suficiente, até porque essa definição não é formal.

O termo sobre o erro não é "impreciso", é "inexato". Pela definição formal geral, que eu não gosto, aquilo é até "exato" (sempre igual), o que não nos ajuda, além de ser "preciso" (é próximo suficiente).

Mas acho que as pessoas entenderam o que quer dizer ali na pergunta/resposta, mesmo estando errado. Só também consolidou o entendimento errado do termo.

Porém, quando o erro é uma oposição, ele deveria ser considerado grave. Mas está tão enraizado que acaba passando batido.

Li em vários lugares que mesmo em outros contextos as pessoas confundem os termos.

## Conclusão

Note que estou respondendo a pergunta, por qualquer definição eles não são intercambiáveis e são diferentes, mas a forma como são diferentes pode mudar se usar a definição formal encontrada no contexto geral ou se observar como ele é usado em algum contexto da computação.

Não estou respondendo no sentido de dar uma resposta canônica que pode ser usada para todos referenciarem para justiciar inequivocamente como usar cada no nosso contexto. Pode ser referenciada para dar um argumento a favor de uma visão.

Então, o que você tem ali, o valor não representa a realidade, ou representa mas cada hora dá uma coisa diferente?

Se ele é exato, ele tem todos detalhes que necessita? Ou seja, nesse exemplo tem todas casas decimais que são úteis? Essa parte causa polêmica por não ter uma definição formal.

Não foi perguntado sobre Machine Learning ou algo assemelhado, é outra estória.

Se alguém tem outra visão, coloque, quem sabe eu possa rever a minha visão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -4):

Um relógio que adianta 15 segundos por dia é inexato.

Mas se ele *sempre* adiantar os mesmos 15 segundos por dia, ele é preciso.

O artigo https://www.forecast.app/faqs/what-is-the-difference-between-accuracy-and-precision tem uma figura com quatro alvos que é uma ilustração muito boa para o caso.