# arredondamentos em javascript

Tags: javascript, float

Como posso fazer arredondamentos em JavaScript a 2 casas que arredonde para cima se o ultimo for um 5.
Por exemplo : 111.115 = 111.12.

se usar o `(111.115).toFixed(2)` o resultado é 111.11 que esta errado.
já tentei o `Math.round` mas também não funciona.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Comment: Tenta usar o `Math.ceil(111.115)`.

Comment: isso retorna 112.

Comment: @LeandroPaixão ele espera 111.12 e não 112, o AP deseja trabalhar com "float". RIHAB, o toFixed está correto, se fizer `(111.116).toFixed(2)` terá 111.12, porque o valor está em 6 (ultimo digito), se fizer `(111.1159).toFixed(2)` ou `(111.11590).toFixed(2)` vai notar que também irá obter o valor 111.12, isso se deve a precisão, recomendo que leia sobre *IEEE 754*.

Comment: `(111.115).toFixed(20) === '111.11499999999999488409'`. Por isso.

Answer (score 0):

O `toFixed` está correto no resultado apresentado, se fizer `(111.116).toFixed(2)` terá 111.12, porque o valor está em 6 (ultimo digito), se fizer `(111.1159).toFixed(2)` ou `(111.11590).toFixed(2)` vai notar que também irá obter o valor 111.12, recomendo que leia sobre *IEEE 754*, sugestão de leitura:

- [O que é IEEE 754?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/3635)

Para arredondar para cima pode usar o `Math.ceil`, mas para isso é necessário que o valor seja um inteiro, então se você precisa que esse arredondamento seja a partir da terceira casa, você pode multiplicar por 1000, aplicar o `Math.ceil` para arredondar e depois dividir novamente, obtendo o resultado aproximado (que dependendo do caso poderá usar `toFixed` posteriormente):

```js
console.log(Math.ceil(16.422 * 1000) / 1000);
console.log(Math.ceil(115.1 * 1000) / 1000);
console.log(Math.ceil(115.11 * 1000) / 1000);
console.log(Math.ceil(115.111 * 1000) / 1000);
console.log(Math.ceil(115.114 * 1000) / 1000);
console.log(Math.ceil(115.1149 * 1000) / 1000);
console.log(Math.ceil(115.115 * 1000) / 1000);
```

Se deseja apenas arredondar, ao invés do `Math.ceil` (arredonda para cima), use o `Math.round`, mas antes multiplique por 1000, isso se deseja que seja a partir a da terceira casa, exemplos:

```js
console.log('16.422 -> ', arredondar(16.422));
console.log('115.114 -> ', arredondar(115.114));
console.log('115.1146 -> ', arredondar(115.1146));
console.log('115.1149 -> ', arredondar(115.1149));
console.log('115.115 -> ', arredondar(115.115));
console.log('115.1151 -> ', arredondar(115.1151));
console.log('115.1159 -> ', arredondar(115.1159));
console.log('115.116 -> ', arredondar(115.116));
console.log('115.1116 -> ', arredondar(115.1116));

function arredondar(valor) {
   return Math.round(valor * 1000) / 1000;
}
```

Note que se o valor for `115.1116` ele irá arredondar para aproximadamente `115.112`, então no caso depende muito de como você deseja trabalhar (a partir de qual casa decimal)

Comment: top, é isso mesmo. muito obrigado

Comment: resolveu um problema mas estragou outro, agora se o valor for 16.422 ele arredonda para 16.43. Nao estou a perceber isto

Comment: eu preciso que ele arredonde de 0-4 para baixo e de 5 a 9 para cima. ex:

111.122 = 111.12, 111.123= 111.12 ;;; 111.125=111.13; 111.126=111.13; 111.128=111.13

Comment: ´´´´´´if(taxaIvaFormatado == "23.0000"){
    i23 = (valorFormatadoComDescontoMaisDescontoGlobalXiVA*100)/100;
     iva23 += i23;
     total23 = Math.round(iva23 * 100) / 100;
     console.log("total23 " + total23)
}´´´´

isto se o iva23 for 111.125 retorna 111.12 e eu quero que retorne 111.13

Comment: @RIHAB como expliquei na pergunta, depende de qual casa decimal você deseja o resultado, no entanto cada proposta que você apresentou aqui são variadas. Vou tentar editar mais uma vez para ver se atende a sua necessidade.

Comment: eu queria que o valor final ficasse a 2 casas decimais, e queria que se a a 3 casa fosse >=5 ele arredondasse para cima. se fosse < que 5 ele arredondasse para baixo como nos exemplos que eu dei.

ex: 
111.122 = 111.12, 
111.123= 111.12 ;;; 
111.125=111.13; 
111.126=111.13; 
111.128=111.13

Comment: @RIHAB isso tudo é devido a precisão, note que `(111.1150001).toFixed(2)` vai gerar `111.12`, enquanto `(111.115).toFixed(2)` vai gerar `111.11`, geralmente com final `.15`, `.115` ou `.1150000`, ou qualquer semelhante, vai ser arredondado para baixo (como pode ver no toFixed, exemplos: `0.15.toFixed(1); 0.15000.toFixed(1)`), se fizer um `0.15.toFixed(18)` vai notar que pe exibido `0.149999999999999994`, resumindo "computadores", sabe como é, né? :) Leia o: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/3635