# Função para arredondar para cima valores decimais terminados em 5

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com alguns dados e preciso corrigir(para o meu caso) o arredondamento realizado pela função round.

```
round(46.675, 2)
# [1] 46.67
```

Preciso que números terminados em 5 passem a ser arredondados para cima.

Valor esperado = 46.68

Comment: Esse arredonamento que o round() lhe apresenta é o comportamento correto, recomendo que leia o [O que é IEEE 754?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/3635). Note que você pode até fazer alguma gambiarra que force o x.675 tornar em x.68, mas isso vai afetar outros números que talvez você não deseje o tal resultado.

Comment: Você pode usar `signif(46.675, 4)`. [documentação](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VFP/versions/1.4.1/topics/Signif)

Comment: @PauloMarques não vai apresentar o resultado em diferentes situações o autor deseja: https://ideone.com/Bigam2, até seria possível fazer uma ***gambiarra*** para limitar ou adicionar duas casas decimais com operações aritméticas, e depois de usar o `signif` você devolveria o valor subtraído, ou removeria o valor extra, você também pode separar a fração do valor do valor em si, aplicar o `signif(«fração», 2)`, mas tudo isso vai depender do que de fato o autor necessita, e ainda poderá existir problemas.

Answer (score 4):

Não uma resposta de como fazer, mas de porque não fazer.

Arredondar valores não é um processo trivial em computação. A explicação é longa e foge dos objetivos de um sítio de perguntas e respostas como o StackOverflow. Uma boa explicação (em inglês) pode ser lida nas vinhetas do [pacote round](https://cran.r-project.org/package=round).

Sem entrar em detalhes, a ideia é: ao arrendondar, está pegando um valor que vem de uma distribuição contínua (e processado em binário) e simplificando para uma representação com número limitado de dígitos em decimal. Se sempre arredondar 5 para cima, estará enviesando seus dados (e futuros cálculos). O ideal seria um algoritmo que nesse caso escolhesse aleatoriamente arredondar para cima ou para baixo metade das vezes que fosse aplicado a um valor, mas isso é impraticável computacionalmente. O método de "arredondar para par" usado pela `round` (seguindo o [o padrão internacional IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) para [aritmética de ponto flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%ADrgula_flutuante)) é uma regra fixa que se aproxima de meio a meio das vezes quando aplicada a um grande número de valores.

Você pode escrever uma função que sempre arredonde 5 para cima, mas isso é altamente não recomendável. Se quer simplificar valores para usar em apresentações, publicações, etc (i.e., não para armazenar seus dados ou usar em outros cálculos), pode usar `signif` para reduzir os valores a um certo número de algarismos significativos:

```
signif(46.675, 4)
#> 46.68
```

Mas fique ciente que a implementação de algarismos significativos também não é trivial.

Answer (score -2):

No R padrão não temos função própria para isso, porém podemos criar uma com base que tenha um comportamento similar ao `round`, exceto quando termina em 5 usando `floor(x +0.5)`:

```r
round_up <- function(x, digitos = 0) {
  sinal = ifelse(x < 0, -1, 1)
  n_digitos = 10^digitos
  floor(x*n_digitos + 0.5* sinal)/n_digitos
}

original = c(46.675,-46.675)
data.frame(original, round = round(original, 2), round_up = round_up(original,2) )
#>   original  round round_up
#> 1   46.675  46.67    46.68
#> 2  -46.675 -46.67   -46.68
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>