# Qual é a diferença entre ponto fixo e ponto flutuante?

Tags: terminologia, matemática, ciência-da-computação, números

Qual seria a explicação simples do que é cada um dos termos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os números normalmente são representados com uma quantidade de dígitos para a parte inteira e um número de dígitos para a parte que chamamos de decimal.

O mesmo vale para o computador que precisa de um número de bits para cada uma dessas duas partes.

De forma simples, o número com ponto fixo tem dígitos/bits fixos para determinar o número em cada parte, enquanto no número de ponto flutuantes ele varia (flutua) para mais ou menos para cada lado de acordo com a necessidade.

Podemos dizer, grosso modo, que o ponto fixo tem realmente duas partes isoladas, enquanto o ponto flutuante tem uma parte e a vírgula que flutua para separar em duas partes.

O ponto flutuante pode ter amplitude enorme, ou precisão enorme ou um equilíbrio. Quanto mais amplitude de valor for necessária, menos precisão é capaz de entregar, já que tem menos espaço para as casas depois da vírgula, chamadas decimais.

O ponto fixo não tem essa flexibilidade, a amplitude e a precisão são fixas, e se ocupar o mesmo espaço, obviamente que tem um limite menor de amplitude e de precisão.

Então o fixo pode ir, por exemplo (o tamanho pode variar em cada implementação), de -999.999.999,999.999 a 999.999.999,999.999 e o flutuante poderia ir de -9,999e15 a 9,999e15, onde as 15 casas vão para um lado ou outro da vírgula.

Note que aí não importa a codificação específica de como representar o número, mesmo em cada um deles é possível codificar de maneiras diferentes. Geralmente se usa mais o ponto flutuante binário, para o qual o processador tem otimizações seguindo o [IEEE 754](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/493487/112052), abrindo mão da exatidão, ou se usa decimal, que dá exatidão ao número, e tem diversas formas de implementar, inclusive especificada pelo IEEE 754, mas geralmente a mais usada é um ou mais inteiros com uma escala.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).